# wsmprovhost.exe do not terminate after closing WsManConnectionInfo

Tags: c#, powershell

I have class (let's call it DbHostWindows) that contains various things about a windows server. I make an instance of this whenever I want to do something remotely on the server. One of the  things this class consist of is a WsManConnection - this is part of the constructor: 
    vWinRM = new WsManConnection(vServerName);

```
public WsManConnection(string wsManHostName) {
    vWsManConnectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri($"http://{wsManHostName}:5985/wsman")) {
        OpenTimeout = WsManDefaultTimeoutInMs,
        OperationTimeout = WsManDefaultTimeoutInMs,
        IdleTimeout = WsManIdleTimeoutInMs 
    };
    Init();
}
```

I have noticed that whenever I run the DbHostWindows constructor I get a wsmprovhost.exe process running on the server.
    "C:\windows\system32\wsmprovhost.exe -Embedding"
I also noticed that the default timeout of such a process apparently is around 24 days. Setting IdleTimeout to 60000 (minimum value) reduce the timeout to a minute.

My problem is that I would like to get rid of the wsmprovhost.exe process earlier  than a minute - in fact as soon as I dispose of the DbHostWindows object and hence the WsManConnectionInfo. I know at this point I will never use this connection again. I can't figure out how to do this, however.

For testing purposes I tried adding these commands in the end of the constructor  in order to try and kill it asap and being sure the connection wasn't used for anything:

```
vWinRm.PowerShell.Stop();
vWinRm.PowerShell.Runspace.Disconnect();
vWinRm.PowerShell.Dispose();
vWinRm.Dispose();
```

Neither seem to affect the wsmprovhost.exe process at all. The wsmprovhost.exe does close after the IdleTimeout is up. As a workaround I could just raise the MaxProcessesPerShell on the server, but I would rather get these processes to close when the DbHostWindows is disposed.

Comment: did you try to use the `using` statement? e.g: `using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()) {}`

Comment: But then I would need to create this PowerShell object whenever I wanted to execute a command? That isn't what I want, since I might need to use the PowerShell object 0 times, 1 time or 30 times before the DbHostWindows object is disposed. I want to create a DbHostWindows object where this Powershell object is a part of - and when I'm done with the DbHostWindows object  everything related to the DbHostWindows object including the Powershell object would be disposed.

Comment: This is the init function in my constructor by the way: 
    private void Init() {
        vRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(vWsManConnectionInfo);
        vRunspace.Open();
        PowerShell = PowerShell.Create();
        PowerShell.Runspace = vRunspace;
    }

Comment: I did try adding the using statement around the whole DbHostWindows object - that still does not remove the wsmprovhost.exe process when it i disposed of.